# How to answer Calculus by Michael Spivak Chapter 5 probem 17.a

Tags: calculus

I know this must be easy but I am learning.

Prove that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} $$

Does not exist.

What I did was:
Say $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} = L$$

- ∃ ε > 0 : ∀ δ > 0 ∃x with |x| < δ and  |$\frac{1}{x}$ -L| ≥ ε

I do not know how to proceed, how can I find that ε?

Comment: Show that $1/x$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\epsilon=1$, for each $\delta>0$ we find an $N$ large enough such that $1/N<\min\{\delta,1/(|L|+1)\}$, then $1/N<1/(|L|+1)$, so $N>|L|+1$ and hence $|1/(1/N)-L|\geq N-|L|>1$.

Comment: Can I know why you got 1/N < min{δ,1/(|L|+1)}?

Comment: Using Archimedean Principle, we always can choose such an $N$

Comment: Archimedean says that, for every positive number $\alpha$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that $1/N<\alpha$.

Comment: Sorry to ask like 1 week later but, how do I know that $|N-L| ≥ N -|L|$?

Comment: This is triangle inequality: $|u-v|\geq|u|-|v|$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the differnce between the right limit and left limit as $x\to 0$

One is diverging to $ +\infty $ and the other to $- \infty$